# how to access nested objects with mustache js templating engine

Tags: javascript, json, mustache, icanhaz.js

I've this json return

```
{
    "timeline": [{
        "id": "2",
        "self": {
            "uid": "2",
            "username": "ptamzz"
        },
        "file": {
            "fid": "43",
            "file_name": "First Name"
        },
        "connection": {
            "fid": "4",
            "username": "tom"
        },
        "action": "viewed your document",
        "time": "2012-01-16 12:23:03",
        "tags": ["Engineering", "Computer Science", "Java", "Java Library"]
    }, {
        "id": "1",
        "self": {
            "uid": "2",
            "username": "ptamzz"
        },
        "file": {
            "fid": "41",
            "file_name": "Write Up"
        },
        "connection": {
            "fid": "4",
            "username": "tom"
        },
        "action": "favorited your document",
        "time": "2012-01-16 12:22:04",
        "tags": ["Design"]
    }]
}
```

According to the tutorial at http://coenraets.org/blog/2011/12/tutorial-html-templates-with-mustache-js/ (Sample 6: Nested Object section), you can access `dot notation` to access the nested objects.

From the above json, I want to retrieve the data like `self.username`, `file.file_name` etc etc.

Now, I've my template as

```
{{#timeline}}
    <li>
        {{self.username}}
    </li>
{{/timeline}}
```

But `self.username` doesn't work.

How do I retrieve these nested values?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I don't think it's the right way to do but since I couldn't find any answers here, I figured out something myself. At least this works.

```
{{#timeline}}
    <li>
        {{#self}}{{username}}{{/self}}
    </li>
{{/timeline}}
```

Comment: dot notation DOES work. There must be an error in your special case. Maybe because "self.username" is in an array and can appear several times.

Comment: i cant get the "dot notation" working for a simple object. =(
eg.  card {
id:10,
name: "maxwell"
}

Comment: Doesn't this depend on the actual processor?

Comment: Check your version number. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9347998/is-it-bad-practice-to-use-dot-notation-in-mustache-php

Answer (score 6):

Dot notation does not work on version 0.4x and below. It worked on "0.7.2".